# How to call a method from controller in extjs

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I have a bar column chart.. I want when I click on the column then the value of it will be shown and call another function where i will call the database thru ajax.

When I click on the column the value is shown but the 2nd part i.e. the 2nd function call is not done.. 
here is my controller code...

```
initializedEvents: false,
init: function() {
    this.control({
        '#barColumnChart': {
            afterlayout: this.afterChartLayout
        }
    });
},
afterChartLayout: function(){
    if(this.initializedEvents==true) return;
    this.initializedEvents=true;
    Ext.getCmp('barColumnChart').series.items[0].on('itemmousedown',function(obj){
        var barData=obj.storeItem.data['source']+ ' &' + obj.storeItem.data['count'];

            // I want to call the dataBaseCall function here

    });
},
dataBaseCall: function(barData){
    alert(barData);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
afterChartLayout: function(){
    var me = this;
    if(this.initializedEvents==true) return;
    this.initializedEvents=true;
    Ext.getCmp('barColumnChart').series.items[0].on('itemmousedown',function(obj){
        var barData=obj.storeItem.data['source']+ ' &' + obj.storeItem.data['count'];

            me.dataBaseCall(barDat);

    });
},
dataBaseCall: function(barData){
    alert(barData);
}
```

You can also add the controller scope to the event but I personally prefer this.

Comment: may i have your mail id i have some  problems in extjs but since the code is too long stackoverflow is not allowing me to paste the complete one so if i get your id i will mail you the code